# Playing m3u8 from Amazon S3 + CloudFront with Signed URL in Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, audio-streaming

I was able to access the playlist file (.m3u8) with signed URL. But the problem is, to access the stream files (.ts) within the playlist, the URL of each file needs to be signed too.

For Example:

I can access playlist.m3u8 with signed URL http://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/playlist.m3u8?Expires=xxxxxxxx&Policy=yyyyyyyyyyyyy&Signature=zzzzzzzzzzzzzz&Key-Pair-Id=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:13
playlist-00000.ts
#EXTINF:12,
playlist-00001.ts
#EXTINF:12,
playlist-00002.ts
```

But each ts file inside it should also be accessed like

http://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/playlist-00000.ts?Expires=xxxxxxxx&Policy=yyyyyyyyyyyyy&Signature=zzzzzzzzzzzzzz&Key-Pair-Id=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

I have to sign every single URL for each .ts files in the playlist.

Unfortunately, I don't see any media player that could handle the appending of the parameters for the URL before it gets the ts files.

If possible, I need a callback from the player like this:

```
public String onStreamFileReadyForPlaying(String pathToTsFile)
{
     //I could append the parameters here
     return pathToTsFile + "?Expires=xxxxxxxx&Policy=yyyyyyyyyyyyy&Signature=zzzzzzzzzzzzzz&Key-Pair-Id=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
}
```

Comment: Please help me i also stuck with same how to do this 1) using Lambda function then please send me any reference video 2) or using code i have to update *.m3u8 file . I am new in AWS and doing same stuck from almost one week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply sign the URLs in the playlist.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hi, do you mean to say, I replace each .ts file name with the whole complete signed URL in the playlists? Like for playlist-00000.ts I replace it with http://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/playlist-00000.ts?Expires=xxxxxxxx&Policy=yyyyyyyyyyyyy&Signature=zzzzzzzzzzzzzz&Key-Pair-Id=kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk ????

Comment: We tried a similar solution before. But we only appended the parameters at the end part without adding the http://..... in front. We thought the player would add them automatically. But now replace it with the full URL like you said and it worked. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @JLT Can you provide some more information on how you are reading the file for per-signing. I also got stuck at the same place

Comment: Please help me i also stuck with same how to do this 1) using Lambda function then please send me any reference video 2) or using code i have to update *.m3u8 file .  I am new in AWS and doing same stuck from almost one week

Answer (score 1):

There is two way of "Using Signed URLs" and "Signed Cookies"

I think that you have to use "Signed Cookies"

I found below of link why use "Signed Cookies"
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

> Use signed cookies in the following cases:
>
> - You want to provide access to multiple restricted files, for example,    all of the files for a video in `HLS format` or all of the
>   files in the    subscribers' area of website.

I didn't try "Signed Cookies" yet. but i have same problem.
if you have been done "Signed Cookies" Can you give feedback?

below of link is document of how to use "Sigend Cookies"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudfront signed urls with custom to allow access to all files inside a folder with a single singature.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)

For that you have generate a cloudfront keypair. To generate go to `my security credentials` in the top drop down and select cloufront. There you can see the option to generate key pair.