# Creating signed URL for private HLS and DASH playlist in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

We have video like `S3/category/guid/HLS and DASH playlists and its files`. It works if I don't restrict Viewer Access. If I restrict and use signed URL the player just loads and never plays. I think it is because it can't access to hls different bitrate files. So do I have to give signed URL for entire folder of that video?

Comment: You can use Custom Policy to create signed URL and you can use Wildcard in the resources while creating signed URL, that way all the url with the same signed url will work.

Comment: @JamesDean can you please explain in more details or post your solution as an answer as I am facing the same issue.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html

Comment: @JamesDean I have created a custom policy with Wildcard and I am successfully able to access any file in that directory but still .m3u8 file does not play in player. I guess .ts files are not using the same sign url.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution yet?

Comment: You need to make sure the player accesses the signed URLs for the playlist files (`.ts`) too, as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621256/playing-m3u8-from-amazon-s3-cloudfront-with-signed-url-in-android

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use Signed cookies to support HLS streaming via Cloudfront.